# What Is The Status Of Narrator "Abdul-Rahman Bin Abi Bakrah"?

Tags: hadith, authenticity, uloom-al-hadith, ilm-mustalah-al-hadith, tradition

I am searching for the reliablity of the narrator Abdul-Rahman Bin Abi Bakrah. He can be found in Bukahri here:-

https://sunnah.com/bukhari/79/47

He is also found in one of the text of a narration in Imam Muwatta here:-

https://sunnah.com/urn/511660

But why did Mullah Ali Qari regarded him as a weak narrator in Mirqat al-Mafatih? Can someone please trace down the following statement from Mullah Ali Qari in his Mirqat al- Mafatih:-

**رواه الترمزي و قال غريب و في اسناده عبد الرحمان بن ابي بكرا المليكي نضعف**

(Mirqat, Volume 5, Page 466)

Thanks.

Comment: These are different people in al-Bukhari it is 'Abdurrahmaan ibn Abi Bakrah بكرة while in al-Muwatta' ft is 'Abdurrahmaan ibn Abi Bakr بكر. The last statement mentions عبد الرحمان بن أبي بكرا المليكي. Note that' Abdurrahmaan ibn Abi Bakr would be in worst case the person who narrated via a Sahabi what the prophet said or rejected or confirmed or did. There shouldn't be more than one intermediate between him and the prophet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up different people.

The person in the isnad of the hadith of Imam Bukhari is Abdur-Rahman ibn Abi Bakrah Ath-Thaqafi (RA). Abu Bakrah's real name was Nufay ibn Al-Harith, and he was a Sahabi. Hence, his son Abdur-Rahman was a Tabi'i.

The person mentioned in the hadith of the Muwatta is Abdur-Rahman ibn Abi Bakr (RA). Abu Bakr (RA) is the famous Abu Bakr (RA) we all know. Abdur-Rahman (RA) was his youngest son and the sister of Aisha (RA).

As for the last one, that is Abdur-Rahman ibn Abi Bakr Al-Maleeki. He was considered weak by many people including Imam Bukhari.